# Parameterized Linq Query -Is there a better performance option?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I am using the following parameterized linq query expression to query from approximately 100,000 records in a SQL server. Is there a better way?

```
public IList<Article> GetArticles(string language, string category, string subcategory, bool exclusives, int pageIndex, int pageSize = 200)
    {

        IQueryable<Article> query;

        query = db.Articles.Where(t => t.IsActive && t.ArticleStatus);

        if (exclusives) { query = query.Where(t => t.IsExclusive); }


        if (language.ToUpper() != "ALL")
        {
            query = query.Where(t => t.Language.ToUpper() == language);
        }
        if (category.ToUpper() != "ALL")
        {
            query = query.Where(t => t.Category.ToUpper() == category);
        }
        if (subcategory.ToUpper() != "ALL")
        {
            query = query.Where(t => t.SubCategory.ToUpper() == subcategory);
        }
        query = query.Where(t => t.ArticleDate <= DateTime.Now);

        query = query.OrderByDescending(t => t.ArticleNo).Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

        if (query.Any() == false)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework isn't known for being the fastest option at runtime--it's supposed to be maintainable, easy, and fast to write. If you want something fast, go with a different ORM that lets you write T-SQL manually (or use EF's `Database.SqlQuery<T>(string)` methods).

That said, you're actually running your query twice.

```
if (query.Any() == false)
{
    return null;
}
else
{
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Each of these methods will execute a varied form of your query against the database.

Instead, test out performance with only calling with once.

```
var returnList = query.ToList();

if (returnList.Count == 0)
{
    return null;
}
else
{
    return returnList;
}
```

The improvement here should be evident, but it's possible that statistics will be messed up on your database, so definitely test.

Aside from that, I would just check indexes. Entity Framework builds its queries in sometimes-unusual ways, so I like to run the query plan explorer (or SQL Profiler) against them.

Simplest way to do that is to put a breakpoint at your `ToList()` call for a few inputs, hover or use the Watch windows to get `query.ToString()`, paste that in something that can get query plans (like VS's database tooling or SSMS), and see if it has anything obvious.

It's sometimes the case that you an rearrange calls to EF to improve the query, but generally the case that you'll want to reassess indexes server-side to meet what EF is giving you.

But, again, remember to do that for varied inputs--you're changing your query, so you want to make sure you've got all your bases covered.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the query running twice. That itself would save a considerable overhead. Is there a way to simplify the 'Ifs' in my query?